# How to change color of righthand inspection bar for "added" and "modified" lines?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

For the most part I've been able to configure all interface colors, but I can't find where to change the inspection bar color for added and modified lines.

It's slightly irritating to have them shine so bright in the middle of a split window.

If changing colors isn't an option, disabling them would be a workaround.

[image: PHPStorm inpsection bar]

Answer (score 4):

Found it!

File -> Settings -> Editor (under IDE Settings) -> Colors & Fonts -> Diff -> Change the "Stripe mark color" for Changed and Inserted

Comment: I actually visited to check if I can change colors of `diff tool` of intellij. Because of this i realised that the settings are actually present to change the color.